# How to config supervisor with Django channels and server daphne

Tags: django, supervisord, django-channels, daphne

I have a problem with my configuration supervisor, my file is in `etc/supervisor/conf.d/realtimecolonybit.conf`,

When I try command supervisorctl reread, show me the "No config updates to processes" and when I try the other command like this

```
supervisorctl status realtimecolonybit
```

Shows me this error

```
realtimecolonybit                FATAL     can't find command '/home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/bin/start.sh;'
```

And when try the supervisorctl start realtimecolonybit
show me this error

```
realtimecolonybit: ERROR (no such file)
```

My configuration in my file realtimecolonybit.conf is below

```
[program:realtimecolonybit]
command = /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/bin/start.sh;
user = root
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/logs/realtimecolonybit.log;
redirect_strderr = true;
```

My configuration from my file start.sh is below

```
     #!/bin/bash
     NAME="realtimecolonybit"
     DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/colonybit
     SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/run/gunicorn.sock

     USER=root
     GROUP=root
     NUM_WORKERS=3
     DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=colonybit.settings

     echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

     cd $DJANGODIR
     source /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/bin/activate
     # workon realtimecolonybit
     export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
     export PYTHONPAHT=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

     RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
     test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

     exec daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 colonybit.asgi:application
```

When I run without supervisor like this

```
(realtimecolonybit)realtimecolonybit/#/ ./bin/start.sh
```

it's run ok and working well, but sometimes down the server

I try to run a Django 1.11 and django_channel with supervisor my app is in aws.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, the error was in file .conf, I remove `;` and remove the `.sh`, change the `start.sh` to `start`

wrong command

```
command = /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/bin/start.sh;
```

correct command

```
command = /home/ubuntu/realtimecolonybit/bin/start
```